# change web api return type

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a web api project and I want to return aspecific json type. I am returning two different arrays but I want it to be as the type I put below.

```
Snippet from my controller


    public IHttpActionResult GetNOX(){
    -------
                List<ListCreator> lisss = new List<ListCreator>();
                lisss.Add(new ListCreator(ısavg, ossbavg, kadavg, benzinavg, dolumavg, harfiyatavg, madenavg));
                return Ok(lisss);
    }

    ------------------
     public class ListCreator
        { 
                public List<double> avg = new List<double>();//ArayLists which contains the industrial sectors and their gas emissions
                public List<string> names = new List<string>();

                public ListCreator(double ısınma, double osb, double kad, double benzin, double dolum, double harfiyat, double maden)//Consructor
                {

                    avg.Add(ısınma);//Adds sector names to arraylist
                    avg.Add(osb);
                    avg.Add(kad);
                    avg.Add(benzin);
                    avg.Add(dolum);
                    avg.Add(harfiyat);
                    avg.Add(maden);

                    names.Add("Isinma");
                    names.Add("OSB");
                    names.Add("KAD");
                    names.Add("Benzin");
                    names.Add("Dolum");
                    names.Add("Harfiyat");
                    names.Add("Maden");


                }
```

My output is

```
[{"avg":[384925464640.5,1215183866.964,255.0,85284076.039996013],"names":      ["Isinma","OSB","Benzin","Harfiyat"]}]
```

I want it to be in the form

```
    data: [
                            ['Isınma Kaynaklı', 56.0],
                            ['OSB', 21.0],
                            ['KAD', 2.3],
                            ['Benzin İstasyonu', 25.0],
                            ['Dolum Tesisleri', 18.6],
                            ['Harfiyat Alanları', 11.8],
                            ['Maden Taş Ocakları', 12.7]
                        ]
```

Comment: What you want is not in json format

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want is to associate a `name` with a `avg`.

What I would do here is create a new class with those two fields and encapsulate what you are trying to model.

Something like

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller you can return a List

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    List<Model> models = new List<Model>
    {
        new Model
        {
            Name = "Name",
            Average = "10.0"
        }
    };

    return models;
}
```

Your JSON on the client will look something like (depending what json formatter you are using)

```
[
    { name: 'name', average: '10.0' }
]
```